# Numerical conformal bootstrap - how is the linear functional for bounding operator dimensions chosen?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, phase-transition, ising-model

In the lecture notes by Simmons-Duffin on the conformal bootstrap (https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07982), he outlines in section 10 how operator dimensions are constrained numerically: we look for a linear functional $ \alpha $ acting on the vector space of functions (defined in eq. 191) of the cross ratios $ u $ and $ v $ for 4 points. If, for a given operator dimension and all possible operator spins, $\alpha$ is always positive, the crossing equation cannot be satisfied and these parameters are ruled out.

The functional $\alpha$ is given to be (eq. 198)
$$\alpha(F) = \sum_{m+n \le \Lambda} a_{mn} \partial_{z}^{m} \partial_{\bar{z}}^{n} F(z,\bar{z})\rvert_{z=\bar{z}=\frac{1}{2}},$$
where the $a_{mn}$ are a collection of coefficients (we are trying to determine if they exist such that this equation is satisfied), $\Lambda$ is some cutoff, F is the function of cross-ratios for a given scaling dimension of the field operator and the dimension and spin of operator in the OPE, and $z$ and $\bar{z}$ are related to the cross-ratios by $u = z \bar{z}$, $v = (1-z)(1-\bar{z})$.

But since $\alpha$ could, in principle, be any linear functional (as illustrated by the example in section 10.5 of the notes), why is it that the above form is chosen for the numerical bootstrap algorithm? I assume that it leads to stricter bounds on the operator dimensions, but if so, why would that be the case?

Comment: The truncated Taylor expansion is a simplification to make the problem computationally tractable - a bit hard to optimize over an infinite dimensional vector space otherwise.